# C# HttpClient not using all established connections to a host with parallel requests

Tags: c#, tcp, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.0

I'm using .NET Framework 4.8 for a console application that manages an ETL process and a .NET standard 2.0 library for the HTTP requests that use the HttpClient. This application is expected to handle millions of records and is long running.

These requests are made in parallel with a maximum concurrency limit of 20.

At application launch, I increase the number of connections .NET can make to a single host in a connection pool via the ServicePointManager. This is a frequent cause for [connection pool starvation, as in .NET Framework it defaults to 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/net-framework-connection-pool-limits/).

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;        

    ...
}
```

This is greater than the number of max concurrent requests allowed to ensure my requests are not being queued up on connections that are already being used.

I then loop through the records and post them to a TPL Dataflow block with the concurrency limit of 20.

This block makes the request on my API client which uses a singleton HttpClient for all requests..

```
public class MyApiClient
{
    private static HttpClient _httpClient { get; set; }
    
    public MyApiClient()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();                
    }       
    
    public async Task<ReturnedObject> UploadNewDocumentAsync(DocParams docParams, DocData docData)
    {           
        MultipartFormDataContent content = ConstructMultipartFormDataContent(docParams);
        HttpContent httpContent = docData.ConvertToHttpContent();           

        content.Add(httpContent);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("document/upload", content))
        {
            return await HttpResponseReader.ReadResponse<ReturnedObject>(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using sysinternals TCPView.exe to view all connections made between the local host and remote host, as well as what the status of those connections are and whether data is actively being sent or not.

When starting the application I see new connections established for each request made, until around 50 connections are established. I also see activity for around 20 at any given time. This meets expectations.

After around 24 hours of activity, TCPView shows only 5 connections concurrently sending and receiving data. All 50 connections still exist and are all in the Established state, but the majority sit idle. I don't have a way of logging when connections stop being actively used. So I don't know whether all of a sudden it drops from using 20 connections to only 5, or whether it gradually decreases.

My log file records elapsed time for every request made and I also see a degradation in performance at this time. Requests take longer and longer to complete, and I see an increase in TaskCanceled exceptions as the HttpClient reaches its timeout value of 100 seconds.

I've also confirmed with the 3rd party API vendor that they are not receiving a large number of incoming requests timing out.

This suggests to me that the application is still trying to make 20 requests at a time, but they are being queued up on a smaller number of TCP connections. All the symptoms point to classic [connection pool starvation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/net-framework-connection-pool-limits/).

While the application is running, I can output some information from the ServicePointManager to the console.

```
ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(myApiService.BasePath, WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy);
Console.WriteLine(            
    $"CurrentConnections: {sp.CurrentConnections} " +
    $"ConnectionLimit: {sp.ConnectionLimit}");
```

Console output:

```
CurrentConnections: 50 ConnectionLimit: 50
```

This validates what I see in TCPView.exe, which is that all 50 connections are still allowed and are established.

The symptoms show connection pool starvation, but TCPView.exe and ServicePointManager show there are plenty of available established connections. .NET is just not using them all. This behaviour only shows up after several hours of runtime. The issue is repeatable. If I close and relaunch the application, it begins by rapidly opening all 50 TCP connections, and I see data being transferred on up to 20 at a time. When I check 24 hours later, the symptoms of connection pool starvation have shown up again.

What could cause the behavior, and is there anything further I could do to validate my assumptions?

Comment: `MyApiClient` constructor seems wrong. Can you reduce this to a code sample that others can run and test with?